# lsmeans for mixed lmer model - error estimates

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, lsmeans

I am curious as to why standard error estimates on lsmeans depend greatly on whether certain other factors in a model are treated as fixed or random effects.
For example, I have measured the fish species richness (FishTaxa) at different statuses of streams and controlling for Site and Station nested within Site. There are three levels of Status at each station: pre-degradation, post-degradation, and post-restoration, and FishTaxa is measured several times at each Station during each level of Status. I am waffling as to whether Site should be fixed or random. Because I have reason to believe that Sites (2 levels) differ in mean FishTaxa, and I want to know how much, I at first included it as a fixed effect.

```
FishTaxa.1 = lmer(FishTaxa~ Status + Site + (1|Site:Station), data = Restoration)

> Anova(FishTaxa1)
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II Wald chisquare tests)

Response: FishTaxa
        Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
Status 20.752  2  3.117e-05 ***
Site   21.199  1  4.140e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I am mainly interested in the effect of Status, so:

```
> lsmeans(FishTaxa1, pairwise ~ Status, adjust = "none")
$lsmeans
 Status             lsmean        SE    df  lower.CL upper.CL
 Post-degradation   8.58895 1.1493805 40.36  6.266612 10.91129
 Post-restoration  12.42125 0.9556837 20.59 10.431366 14.41113
 Pre-degradation   12.52084 0.9650306 21.38 10.516134 14.52554

Results are averaged over the levels of: Site
Confidence level used: 0.95 

$contrasts
 contrast                               estimate       SE     df t.ratio p.value
 Post-degradation - Post-restoration -3.8322998 0.9055777 163.26  -4.232  <.0001
 Post-degradation - Pre-degradation  -3.9318871 0.9184968 163.40  -4.281  <.0001
 Post-restoration - Pre-degradation  -0.0995872 0.6374008 158.83  -0.156  0.8760
```

Notice the SE column of the lsmeans table.

Then I tried it with Site as a random effect:

```
FishTaxa.2 = lmer(FishTaxa~ Status + (1|Site) + (1|Site:Station), data = Restoration)

> Anova(FishTaxa2)
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II Wald chisquare tests)

Response: FishTaxa
        Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
Status 20.774  2  3.082e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

> lsmeans(FishTaxa2, pairwise ~ Status, adjust = "none")
$lsmeans
 Status              lsmean       SE   df  lower.CL upper.CL
 Post-degradation   8.586036 4.189446 1.06 -37.90015 55.07222
 Post-restoration  12.417805 4.140499 1.01 -38.63466 63.47027
 Pre-degradation   12.522325 4.142663 1.02 -38.30922 63.35387

Confidence level used: 0.95 

$contrasts
 contrast                              estimate        SE     df t.ratio p.value
 Post-degradation - Post-restoration -3.8317698 0.9055658 163.26  -4.231  <.0001
 Post-degradation - Pre-degradation  -3.9362897 0.9185156 163.40  -4.285  <.0001
 Post-restoration - Pre-degradation  -0.1045199 0.6374487 158.84  -0.164  0.8700
```

Notice the lsmeans are virtually identical, but the SE are much larger. And look at those confidence limits! When plotted in a bar graph, the error bars would suggest the differences between levels aren't significant, but they are according to the contrast, which are again basically the same as with Site as a fixed effect. I did notice when Site was included as a fixed effect, lsmeans notifies my "Results are averaged over the levels of: Site". Why would it not do this when it is a random effect? For inference, at least in this example, I get the same result either way, but for displaying the results, those SE and CI are really weird. Help understanding what is going on and the best way to present this would be appreciated.

Comment: FWIW I agree that Site should almost certainly be included as fixed effect. What's probably happening in your random-effect model is that the among-site variance is being estimated as zero, so the model is essentially *ignoring* the effect of Site

Comment: Thanks, Ben. I'm new to this....sorry about posting on the wrong page....

Comment: no problem, people do it all the time

Comment: that is why I posted here! Because I find lots of results for my google searches on Stack Overflow. I think you've basically answered my question, but is there a way to "migrate" this over into Cross Validated or are these sites unrelated?

Comment: if enough high-rep users (5) vote that it should be closed and migrated to Cross Validated that will happen automatically.  If you prefer you could delete it yourself and re-post there.